# Nouveau doesn't work after upgrade to Debian Wheezy

Tags: xorg, kms, nouveau

I upgraded from Debian squeeze to wheezy. My box contains an old graphics card not supported by current Nvidia drivers for distros newer than lenny (NV5M64 [RIVA TNT2 Model 64/Model 64 Pro]), so in my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, I had `Driver "nv"` specified in squeeze (which didn't seem to work after the update to wheezy).

After reading the internets for a bit, I found that my card should be supported by the `nouveau` driver. Replacing `Driver "nv"` by `Driver "nouveau"` in my xorg.conf still didn't produce a useable X.

I read a bit more and made sure to remove any and all proprietary pieces of Nvidia stuff, including drm and whatnot. Just going with the non-free drivers, as suggested in many internet posts, was no option: Remember that Nvidia dropped the driver for my TNT2 card for everything newer than lenny. Anyhow, still no success.

The only way I got *any* type of X working was using the "vesa" driver, but only in a resolution lower than my LCD monitor's native 1280x1024.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solves the problem is enabling KMS (kernel modesetting). [This post on the Debian lists](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2011/07/msg00270.html) showed me how to track down the problem:

> Looks like Kernel Modesetting is disabled, either through a boot
>   parameter or via a file in /etc/modprobe.d.  Try reloading the nouveau
>   kernel module:

```
# rmmod nouveau
# modprobe nouveau modeset=1
restart X
```

For some reason, `grub` was configured to disable modesetting (maybe to work around a graphics problem I had with an earlier debian version and respective driver – don't remember…). Adding a new menu entry without `nomodesetting` does the trick, even when doing a fresh boot.

The dirty hack is to remove the word `nomodesetting` from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. However, the first few lines in this file say:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
```

This means that the dirty hack works only as long as `upgrade-grub` is not run, which happens each time you do `apt-get upgrade` when there's a new kernel version installed.

**The permanent fix goes like this**:

1. Remove `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodesetting"` from `/etc/default/grub`.
2. Run `# update-grub`.
3. Watch the progress: `Generating grub.cfg ... done`.
4. Enjoy.